# Device ID and OS build number in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Here i like to know about

How to get a Device ID and OS build number in ElectronJS.

I have followed this [link](https://github.com/automation-stack/node-machine-id). but its returning the different device id when compared to my device ID and no idea about OS build.

Help me out,

Regards,

Nandha.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get information about your os/computer with the node built in package: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os

In Electron you can reach the os information in the main process instead of render process. You can easily watch the events between render and main process.

Description for ipcMain events: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.In that doc i didn't see things related to device id.